# Nuxt 3 SSR , dynamic pages with nuxt-link

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, routerlink, nuxt-link

I am using Nuxt 3 ssr app the page is using asyncdata to fetch record it is working fine.
but once i add nuxt-link to dynamic page . it says it is not matching with any page.

```html
name: `flights-from-${
                promoReward.origin.city_en_slug
              }-${promoReward.origin?.iata.toLowerCase()}`,
```

the above code is generating the proper link but on serverside it doesnt match. if i copy and past in new tab then the dynamic page is loading.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to give path instead of name or check that the name is proper according to the folder structure